# Wrap a method with variable arguments in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, overloading

I need to wrap a method with variable arguments.  For example:

```
function p = plot3ex(varargin)

p1 = varargin{1};
p2 = varargin{2};

x = [p1(1,1) p2(1,1)];
y = [p1(2,1) p2(2,1)];
z = [p1(3,1) p2(3,1)];

extraArgs = varargin(3:end);

p = plot3(x,y,z,extraArgs);
```

When I call this function in the following manner:

```
p = plot3ex(p1,p2,'--k','DisplayName','My plot 1');
```

I get the following error:

> Error using `plot3`
>   Not enough input arguments.

Basically what I need is a method that receives as input two points and any configuration of `plot3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`varargin` and ultimately `extraArgs` is a cell array of contents.  Unpack the rest of the variables as a [comma separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html):

```
p = plot3(x, y, z, extraArgs{:});
```

Note that the use of **curly braces** - `{}` is important.  How you are calling `plot3` currently resolves to the following equivalent function call:

```
p = plot3(x, y, z, {extraArgs{1}, extraArgs{2}, ..., extraArgs{end});
```

The fourth input parameter is resolved to be a cell array of contents.  This is why you are getting an error because what is expected are pairs of strings / flags and associated values. How you are doing it currently is not correct. You need to **unpack** the contents of the cell array, but ensuring that the elements are placed in a comma-separated list.

Doing `extraArgs{:}` is equivalent to doing `extraArgs{1}, extraArgs{2}, ..., extraArgs{end}`, which is what you would put into the function manually if you were to call `plot3`.  You are replacing manually specifying the rest of the input parameters by accessing each element in the cell array and splitting up the elements into a comma separated list.

Therefore, doing `extraArgs{:}` instead resolves to the following equivalent function call:

```
p = plot3(x, y, z, extraArgs{1}, extraArgs{2}, ..., extraArgs{end});
```

... which is what is expected.

---

## Example run

```
p1 = [0 0 0].';
p2 = [1 1 1].';
p = plot3ex(p1,p2,'--k','DisplayName','My plot 1');
```

This gives me:

[image]

Comment: Not enough input arguments.
Error in plot3ex (line 40)
    p = plot3(x,y,z,extraArgs(:));

Comment: Using extraArgs{:} works for you? Did you used the same inputs I do? It is not working for me.

Comment: @Pedro77 I've updated my post with a working example.  Also, you have to use **curly braces** `{}`... **NOT ROUND BRACES**.  Your comment is using ROUND braces.

Comment: Ok! My mistake! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Pedro77 You're very welcome :) For a minute I got nervous lol.  Thanks for keeping me on my toes!